# Conversion Type From DBNull to String is Not Valid

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

hello guys i'm having problems on displaying data on vb.net from database. here's my problem i want to display the image on vb.net via path. but of the record doesn't have an image it will fall to condition where i will fix it to a image via path
(Sorry for my bad English.)

```
    Public Sub DisplayData()
    txtID.Text = DSDrvSchool.Tables("Command Out").Rows(Index).Item(0)
    txtlname.Text = DSDrvSchool.Tables("Command Out").Rows(Index).Item(1)
    txtfname.Text = DSDrvSchool.Tables("Command Out").Rows(Index).Item(2)
    txtmid.Text = DSDrvSchool.Tables("Command Out").Rows(Index).Item(3)
    txtstreet.Text = DSDrvSchool.Tables("Command Out").Rows(Index).Item(4)
    txtBarang.Text = DSDrvSchool.Tables("Command Out").Rows(Index).Item(5)
    txtcity.Text = DSDrvSchool.Tables("Command Out").Rows(Index).Item(6)
    txtzip.Text = DSDrvSchool.Tables("Command Out").Rows(Index).Item(7)
    cmbGender.Text = DSDrvSchool.Tables("Command Out").Rows(Index).Item(8)
    txtcontact.Text = DSDrvSchool.Tables("Command Out").Rows(Index).Item(9)
    txtemail.Text = DSDrvSchool.Tables("Command Out").Rows(Index).Item(10)
    cmbmonth.Text = DSDrvSchool.Tables("Command Out").Rows(Index).Item(11)
    cmbday.Text = DSDrvSchool.Tables("Command Out").Rows(Index).Item(12)
    cmbyear.Text = DSDrvSchool.Tables("Command Out").Rows(Index).Item(13)
    txtage.Text = DSDrvSchool.Tables("Command Out").Rows(Index).Item(14)
    cmbmarital.Text = DSDrvSchool.Tables("Command Out").Rows(Index).Item(15)
    txtemerlname.Text = DSDrvSchool.Tables("Command Out").Rows(Index).Item(16)
    txtemerfname.Text = DSDrvSchool.Tables("Command Out").Rows(Index).Item(17)
    txtemercontact.Text = DSDrvSchool.Tables("Command Out").Rows(Index).Item(18)
    cmbcourse.Text = DSDrvSchool.Tables("Command Out").Rows(Index).Item(19)
    cmbmeet1.Text = DSDrvSchool.Tables("Command Out").Rows(Index).Item(20)
    cmbmeet2.Text = DSDrvSchool.Tables("Command Out").Rows(Index).Item(21)
    cmbmeet3.Text = DSDrvSchool.Tables("Command Out").Rows(Index).Item(22)
    cmbfrom.Text = DSDrvSchool.Tables("Command Out").Rows(Index).Item(23)
    cmbto.Text = DSDrvSchool.Tables("Command Out").Rows(Index).Item(24)
    txtPath.Text = DSDrvSchool.Tables("Command Out").Rows(Index).Item(25)
    'pbImage.Image = Image.FromFile(DSDrvSchool.Tables("Command Out").Rows(Index).Item(25))
    If txtage.Text Is Nothing Then
        pbImage.Image = Image.FromFile("D:\JCH Folder\Programming\My1stSystem\DrivingSchoolManagementSystem\Database\Photos")
    Else
        pbImage.Image = Image.FromFile(DSDrvSchool.Tables("Command Out").Rows(Index).Item(25))
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

IsDBNull is the solution. Follow the link

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.isdbnull%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You should check for `DbNull` before accessing the value...

```
' ...

If DSDrvSchool.Tables("Command Out").Rows(Index).Item(25) Is DbNull.Value Then
    pbImage.Image = Image.FromFile("D:\JCH Folder\Programming\My1stSystem\DrivingSchoolManagementSystem\Database\Photos")
Else
    pbImage.Image = Image.FromFile(DSDrvSchool.Tables("Command Out").Rows(Index).Item(25))
End If
```

End Sub

Comment: guys is't possible to view incomplete records(from access). i think that is the real problem here.